# Checking type of component(2D-Roguelike source)

Tags: unity-game-engine

to start off, I'm very new to Unity and pretty new to C# as well. I'm trying to edit the code where the player is able to damage walls to also allow him to damage enemies. Currently, I'm just trying to get colliding with the enemy to do something other than just reduce my health. The following code is trying to check the type of whatever I've collided with and act accordingly. if I hit a wall, it should reduce the walls health. If I collide into something else, it should print to the console. looking around, I thought that I was supposed to do this inside of the player.cs:

```
 protected override void OnCantMove <T> (T component)
 {

         //Set hitWall to equal the component passed in as a parameter.
         Wall hitWall = component as Wall;
         Enemy hitEnemy = component as Enemy;

     if (hitWall){
         //Call the DamageWall function of the Wall we are hitting.
         hitWall.DamageWall (wallDamage);
         //Set the attack trigger of the player's animation controller in order to play the player's attack animation.
         animator.SetTrigger ("playerChop");
     }else{
         print ("The collision is not a wall");
     }
 }
```

I also attempted to use if(component is Wall){...}else{...}, but it seems that no matter what I hit, I can't get the else statement to print anything to the console. I also tried making the else statement modify the foodText.text just in case print wasn't working for some reason, but that also didn't work. This has me thinking that the collision won't interact with anything other than Walls, but I'm not sure how to change that. I know that the moving uses a linecast to check on the blockinglayer, but I know that Enemies are also on that layer and it seems that colliding with them won't do anything either.

I apologize if I'm a moron and am just missing something super simple or if I'm just completely clueless, but I've spent a while trying to figure this out and it just hasn't come to me.

Comment: why don't you just use Tags instead? Mark the items you need with proper tags and then check for the [tag](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html) of the item you collided with.

Answer (score 0):

This all looks quite complicated. What I would do is just add a rigidbody to the player and a collider to all walls, enemies and the player. Then in your players script add something like this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    string colliderTag = collision.gameObject.tag;
    if(colliderTag == "Wall") {
        collision.gameObject.SendMessage("ApplyDamage", damageToApply, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
    } else if(colliderTag == "Enemy") {
        ApplyDamage(damageToApplyToPlayer);
    }
}
```

Also make sure for every wall give it the tag `Wall` and for each enemy give it the tag `Enemy`. Now this script assumes that somewhere on your wall you have a health script that has a method in it named `ApplyDamage`, as well as having this method in your player script. Im assuming this method would look a little something like this:

```
public void ApplyDamage(float damage) {
    health -= damage;
}
```

So make sure to include this where ever you store Wall health, and also include it in player.cs. However if you have an external script for storing player health, alter the first block of code to the following:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    string colliderTag = collision.gameObject.tag;
    if(colliderTag == "Wall") {
        collision.gameObject.SendMessage("ApplyDamage", damageToApply, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
    } else if(colliderTag == "Enemy") {
        gameObject.GetComponent<healthScriptName>().ApplyDamage(damageToApplyToPlayer);
    }
}
```

In this case you can have an external health script for the player but it still must be attached to the player.